# Microsoft XAudio2Sound3D sample code' does not send submix voice to mastering voice

Tags: xaudio2

I am studying Microsoft XAudio2's X3Daudio sample code and have confused about sending the source voice parallel to both submix voice and mastering voice.

```
if( FAILED( hr = g_audioState.pXAudio2->CreateMasteringVoice( &g_audioState.pMasteringVoice ) ) )
{
    SAFE_RELEASE( g_audioState.pXAudio2 );
    return hr;
}
if( FAILED( hr = g_audioState.pXAudio2->CreateSubmixVoice( &g_audioState.pSubmixVoice, 1,
                                                           nSampleRate, 0, 0,
                                                           nullptr, &effectChain ) ) )
{
    SAFE_RELEASE( g_audioState.pXAudio2 );
    SAFE_RELEASE( g_audioState.pReverbEffect );
    return hr;
}
```

//above second last argument nullptr->without sendlist pointer to submix voice, what I understand is, there is no output from this submix voice.

```
XAUDIO2_SEND_DESCRIPTOR sendDescriptors[2];
sendDescriptors[0].Flags = XAUDIO2_SEND_USEFILTER; // LPF direct-path
sendDescriptors[0].pOutputVoice = g_audioState.pMasteringVoice;
sendDescriptors[1].Flags = XAUDIO2_SEND_USEFILTER; // LPF reverb-path -- omit for better performance at the cost of less realistic occlusion
sendDescriptors[1].pOutputVoice = g_audioState.pSubmixVoice;
const XAUDIO2_VOICE_SENDS sendList = { 2, sendDescriptors };

// create the source voice
V_RETURN( g_audioState.pXAudio2->CreateSourceVoice( &g_audioState.pSourceVoice, pwfx, 0,
                                                    2.0f, nullptr, &sendList ) );
```

the source voice will send the sound to both mastering voice and submix voice. submix voice will ad reverb effect on the sound. But I don't see where submix voice send the post-processing and reverb effect enable sound to the mastering voice to output to the speaker.

If submix voice will default send its sound data to mastering voice if you do not specify the sendlist when you create it. Why in this sample, we also need send source voice to mastering voice at the same time? The demo output sound always with reverb effect on it. I don't see there is an option to disable the reverb effect in the sample executable.

I am so confused.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not provide a send list, then a voice is automatically connected to the mastering voice. Per [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/microsoft.directx_sdk.ixaudio2.ixaudio2.createsubmixvoice.aspx):

```
pSendList [in, optional]
    Pointer to a list of XAUDIO2_VOICE_SENDS structures that describe
    the set of destination voices for the submix voice. If pSendList is
    NULL, the send list will default to a single output to the first
    mastering voice created.
```

If you provide a send list, however, then the output of the voice does not go to the mastering voice unless you specify it in the sendlist. Hence why the source voice specifically sends to both the mastering voice and the submix voice.

The reason that reverb is done on the submix voice is an optimization. It allows all the reverb-affected source voices to do their processing including filtering and source-rate conversions into the submix voice, and then the often expensive effect (in this case the environment reverb) can run once instead of per-source-voice. Further, the submix voice is made to be mono instead of multi-channel so any stereo or multi-channel sources are down-mixed into the submix voice as well prior to the effect processing. Thirdly, this allows you to send some voices to the mastering voice and not the submix voice to be excluded from the reverb (typically HUD and interface sounds).

> Note that the latest version of the XAudio2 samples can be found on [GitHub](https://github.com/walbourn/directx-sdk-samples). You might also want to take a look at [DirectX Tool Kit for Audio](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/Audio).